# Writing binary to a file is pulling incorrect data from previous unrelated popen commands in C

Tags: c, binary, popen, fwrite, simultaneous

So this code functions by itself, but when I use it with my main program, it's somehow pulling in some, what seems to be, completely unrelated parts of the code and writing it to the file I'm writing...  All compiles without issues, so I know it's not a definition problem or a pointer issue, and everything else writes properly, but somehow I'm getting over 3200 bytes of stuff that the struct doesn't have any relation to, and writing it at address 0x1 in the file, which isn't any part of the struct either...

```
struct a {
    unsigned long addr; //File address
    int sz; //Num Bytes
    unsigned long pos; // Buffer Address
};

// Many more than this, but you get the general struct idea..
struct a as[][3] = {
    {{ 0xF245, 5, 0x6F02C4 }},
    {{ 0x471D, 128, 0x65892 }},
    {{ 0x6198F, 12, 0xA4092 }}
}

//Failing code
        fdin = fopen(files[FIRSTFILE]->filename, "rb");

        fdout = fopen(files[SECONDFILE]->filename, "r+b");

        if (!fdin) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", files[FIRSTFILE]->filename);
            fclose(fdin);
            cleanup(ONSCREEN);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (!fdout) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", files[SECONDFILE]->filename);
            fclose(fdout);
            fclose(fdin);
            cleanup(ONSCREEN);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

I have other code here, but none that read from a file and write to another like this, But somewhere in here it's writing at least 3200 bytes incorrectly in the range address 0x1-0xC88 in the file and pulling in data that I'm using in popen functions before all of this.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])); i++) {

            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            fseek(fdin, as[i]->pos, SEEK_SET);
            fread(buffer, 1, as[i]->sz, fdin);

            fseek(fdout, as[i]->addr, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(buffer, 1, as[i]->sz, fdout);
        }

        if(fclose(fdout)==EOF || fclose(fdin)==EOF) {
            logit(ONSCREEN, "Error closing files.\n\n");
            cleanup(ONSCREEN);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        fflush(fdin);
        fflush(fdout);
```

Here's a piece of the code from the main program that somehow it's pulling information from:

```
        sleep(1);
        memset(command, 0x00, 256);
        sprintf(command, "./somecommand");
        fp = popen(command, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            logit(ONSCREEN, "popen failed.");
            cleanup(ONSCREEN);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        while(fgets(store, sizeof(store), fp)) {
            if (strstr(store, "Expected Output")) {
            break;
            }
        }
        pclose(fp);
        fflush(fp);
```

Again, all of these function just fine by themselves, but when put together in a single function, they don't play well together... The files (FILE *fp, *fdin, *fdout) are differently named, and the store character array is named differently than buffer. What have I done wrong here?

Seems to be something unsafe about using popen and fopen in the same function like that or something I'm not clearing out properly here...?

Comment: Can you post a small, self-contained compilable example?  It's hard to know how the snippets of the code you've posted might be interacting. Also, you're not checking the returns from your I/O calls, so maybe an I/O error is affecting the results?  And what type is `buffer`?  I hope it's an array, not a pointer.

Comment: If you failed to open `fdout`, using `fclose(fdout)` in the error path will lead to crashes.  Similarly for `fdin`.  This isn't your immediate problem; it is a potential problem in your error paths.  You are not checking your `fread()` and `fwrite()` calls; that is worrying (especially `fread()`).

Comment: Well I don't think it's an I/O error because it's doing everything it's supposed to.  this extra modification is somehow happening ON TOP of what it's already doing... buffer is a char[256] array.

Comment: Bah, didn't know Enter added the comment... I was trying to separate a line, I'll get a working compile in a few minutes and post it up.

Comment: Also, you almost certainly want a `<` instead of a `<=` in this: `for (int i = 0; i <= (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])); i++)`

Comment: You can edit your own comments for up to 5 minutes; the 'return means submit' catches me every so often, even now.

Comment: How does the size of the buffer you're reading/writing out of have any direct relationship to the index of the `as` array that you're getting the file position and I/O sizes from?  That seems like a bug even if the `as[]` array happens to have the same number of elements as `buffer[]` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `as[]` has 3 elements (your real-life code may have a different number)

```
// Many more than this, but you get the general struct idea..
struct a as[][3] = {
    {{ 0xF245, 5, 0x6F02C4 }},
    {{ 0x471D, 128, 0x65892 }},
    {{ 0x6198F, 12, 0xA4092 }}
}
```

However, you're using the number of elements in `buffer` (which in a comment you say is `char buffer[256]` to index it:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])); i++) {

        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        fseek(fdin, as[i]->pos, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buffer, 1, as[i]->sz, fdin);

        fseek(fdout, as[i]->addr, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, as[i]->sz, fdout);
    }
```

Change the `for` loop to (note also that the test is changed from `<=` to `<`):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(as) / sizeof(as[0])); i++)
```

Finally - I think you're making things unnecessarily more complicated (and probably buggy) by using a 2 dimensional array for `as` for no reason.  try:

```
struct a as[] = {
    { 0xF245, 5, 0x6F02C4 },
    { 0x471D, 128, 0x65892 },
    { 0x6198F, 12, 0xA4092 }
}


// ...
   for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(as) / sizeof(as[0])); i++) {

        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        fseek(fdin, as[i].pos, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buffer, 1, as[i].sz, fdin);

        fseek(fdout, as[i].addr, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, as[i].sz, fdout);
    }
```

Comment: Now I understand your question, I just realized I mis-posted that... when re-naming what's in my code to something less revealing to what my project is based around I mistakenly changed that to "buffer" instead of as... In my code it is correctly referencing the size of the struct, not buffer.  Almost got a working code to post up.

Comment: Strange, in the test code I copied out and did a smaller test on, it worked without issue.. I have to look at what is different in my main code and make sure I haven't made any more "duh" mis-references... Thanks for the other information though, I was definitely making that too complicated. I would mark this as an answer, but it would be misleading as it's not quite the answer for the main issue, and it won't let me up-vote it cause I don't have enough rep...

Comment: Actually I think this did fix it, because it's working properly after I made these changes.  So thanks!